# Compile two versions of C# program automatically

Tags: c#, compilation

I have to make the same program for two different companies (different logo, different name).
I would like to have this done automatically when I do a release.

I am thinking to use a resource file or a satellite assembly, but I am not sure how to proceed.

Which way do you think is the best?

Thanks.

EDIT:

- The differences are only one image and one string.
- I would like to
  have everything generated in one click.
- We might get more clients in
  the future.
- I must also add that I use SmartAssembly to merge all my dependencies into one exe file.

Comment: Depends on exactly what is required, is it just text (and external) branding resources or...? As soon as X wants features Y or has business logic Z ...

Comment: Hi, this is mixed resources, one image and one string. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Potential for more clients screams modularity. This is what dlls were made for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best I can think of it a batch script.

Get your project to reference files (images (logo), text (company name), etc). i.e. C:\MyProject\Resources. So that when the project builds it complies them into the application/installer etc.

This way, you can write a script (.bat file) which copies in the resources needed per company.

Step 1 - Delete all files in the Resources folder

Step 2 - Use MSBuild.exe to build you project

Step 3 - Copy the files needed from the bin/release folder to a directory (i.e. C:\Release\CompanyA)

Step 4 - Change the variables in the script to load the details for the next company. And repeat from step 1, so it copies over the needed resource files and rebuilds.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I haven't thought of that, it might be actually the best solution.

Comment: Its a simple solution (not at all elegant), but if you are doing more and more companies, I advise you go with the other solutions like using DLLs as modules. Or if you get more customisations, consider using something like Git/SVN and branch the project. Then automate a checkout and build using tools like TeamCity

Comment: Finally I made a batch and Im using a conditional compilation symbol to get the correct Resource file.

Comment: @Abatonime Way too much when you consider all you have to do is compile to different folders. Right now it compiles to Debug and Release right? You can change those, and add more builds.

Answer (score 4):

You could create a class library that contains 99% of the code, and then have two projects which each reference the common library with the 1% that differs for each company.  Then a build of the whole solution will generate an executable for each company.  Use this if the differences between what each company wants is just enough that you need to have [slightly] different code.

Alternatively, you could make the sections that vary dependent on data, not code.  In this case, it might mean getting the logo from a file, rather than embedding it in the executable, and having a configuration xml file with the company name.  This would allow you to have just a single executable for both companies.

Comment: @Xaade Did you stop reading after the first paragraph?  And also, there are specific projects that may very well only have two clients, or more likely one build for "everyone" and one for the company that paid to have a custom feature added in just for them.

Comment: Yeah, the first one hurt my eyes.

Comment: He specifically asked the question for how to make two compilations, so I answered that first, and then immediately followed that up with what he should do (if possible) that doesn't involve multiple compilation.

Comment: If a doctor asked how to decapitate, I'd respond with "Why do you need to do that?", not explain how. Bad practice is bad practice. Besides, the second half of his question shows that he's leaning towards an external source of the data.

Comment: At my work, we have a master solution that mimics Servy's first paragraph there.  Albeit, it's not as simple as swapping a couple configuration-level options (they're actually full application implementations on top of our common proprietary framework).  But this master solution builds Silverlight, Android, and WPF (and unit test projects) applications simultaneously and allows us to quickly test/see when changes in our base framework affect each client application.  Best practice?  Not sure, but it works fine for us.

Comment: I'm looking for the best way of doing it. Multiple compilation, external resources, or any other.

Comment: @Abatonime that might be a way to consider.  It allows you to create specific projects with different compilation targets, reference special external resources/DLLs, or include individualized code.  If you're really only swapping image/text resources with the same compilation targets, then perhaps its better to run through essentially configuration/resource files.

Answer (score 2):

Resource string in separate assembly would be the easiest distribution.

But honestly, I'd have it be a customization feature.
Last thing you want is to maintain everyone's logo changes due to: legal reasons, copywrite cases, whimsical artistic license, etc.

Which is short for.... have them provide a formatted image, and have them assign the company name during installation and store that off in the registry or in a meta file of some type (XML, manifest, etc.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How can I have the 2 versions of the separate assembly in one VS project?

Comment: @Abatonime You'd compile them to different folders.